# PHP PDO transactions to prevent double spending?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions, acid

I have a "points" table with a "player" column and an "fpp" column representing some spendable type of points.

I need a function which will subtract x fpp's from a particular player's balance IFF they have >=x fpp's available. The function should return true if the player's balance was decreased or false if there were insufficient funds.

I need to prevent any instances of double spending which, from what I can tell, I'll need transactions for. Using PDO I've thrown together the following:

```
function subFPP($player,$x){
    global $dbh;
    $didSub = false;
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT fpp FROM points WHERE player=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($player));
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if($row && $row[0]>=$x){
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE points SET fpp=fpp-? WHERE player=?");
        $stmt->execute(array($x,$player));
        $didSub = true;
    }
    if($dbh->commit()){
        return $didSub;
    }
    return false;   
}
```

This appears to behave as intended but I've never worked with transactions before and I'm not really sure whether this is doing what I need it to. If two calls are made to this function simultaneously only one should go through (assuming x is more than half the available balance). Will this protect me against double spending or have I screwed something up here? Any improvements?

Also - All the PDO transaction snippets I've seen things are surrounded with try/catch and include a rollBack call in the error block. There's no reason to rollback here for a single insertion/update?

Comment: Why not just add `WHERE player=? AND fpp>?` where that's the player ID and amount they're trying to spend? That way the query will not run unless they're sufficiently funded.

Comment: Wow, great suggestion. Will I still need to begin/commit a transaction with that single query (it reads then writes) or will mysql take care of that for me?

Comment: There's really no point in having a transaction for a single query, they're atomic by definition. Transactions are used for grouping together multiple statements.